# Cypress: Is it possible to select an item out of a dynamic dropdown with only a partial word/s?

Tags: drop-down-menu, cypress

I have a dropdown list which is always increasing in the number of options available. I Have the 'RecieptName' from the option, however, it is followed by text that is constantly changing. eg: RecieptName: 'Changing sentence including words and numbers'.

What I am trying to do is something along the lines of:

```
cy.get('#RecieptName').select('RecieptName:');
```

However, it can't find an option with it as it is followed by changing the numbers. Is it possible to find the option based on a partial option?

[image]

Comment: For words and numbers you can use `.contains(/^RecieptName: .+/)`

Comment: Can you add the HTML of your dropdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option containing the the text "RecieptName:" can be selected by adding `:contains()`

```js
cy.get('#RecieptName option:contains(RecieptName:)')
  .then($option => {
    cy.get('#RecieptName').select($option.text())
  })
```

```js
cy.get('#RecieptName option:contains(RecieptName:)')
  .then($option => {
    cy.get('#RecieptName').select($option.index())
  })
```

Answer (score 3):

You would need to scan the options first, find it's index and select by number

**Using .contains() command**

```js
cy.get('option')
  .contains('ReceiptName:')
  .invoke('index')           // index among siblings
  .then(index => {
    cy.get('dropdown').select(index);
  })
```

**Using a regex**

```js
cy.get('option')
  .contains(/^ReceiptName:/)
  .invoke('index')           // index among siblings
  .then(index => {
    cy.get('dropdown').select(index);
  })
```

**Using selected prop**

```js
cy.get('#RecieptName option')
  .contains(/^ReceiptName:/)
  .invoke('prop', 'selected', true)
```

Answer (score 0):

`filter` will get the DOM element that match a specific selector. Once we get the element, then we get the exact text of **RecieptName** option by using the `invoke(text)` and then we pass the same text to the `select` command, something like this:

```js
cy.get('#RecieptName option')
  .filter(':contains("RecieptName:")')
  .invoke('text')
  .then((recieptNameText) => {
    cy.get('dropdown').select(recieptNameText)
  })
```

You can also use the `value` attribute to directly select the dropdown as I can see the value attributes are unique, I guess that would be the cleanest way to do this:

```js
cy.get('select#RecieptName').select('scoredesc')
cy.get('select#RecieptName').select('modifieddesc')
cy.get('select#RecieptName').select('createdasc')
```